# Using type FileInfo in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to use FileInfo for a DataTemplate in WPF XAML.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type FileInfo}">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=FullName}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Problem is

> FileInfo is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.

I tried to use a namespace alias xmlns:io= and found some System.IO entries but none of them provided a type FileInfo. For example:

```
xmlns:io="clr-namespace:System.IO;assembly=WindowsBase"
```

So the question is: is it possible and how to?

Comment: A simple way is a `FileInfoViewModel` wrapping `FileInfo` and exposing its properties.

Comment: Message "... is not supported in a ... (WPF) project" is related to some tag in XAML. Looks like there are `<io:FileInfo>` tag somewhere. Data templates allow to define template for any type. Please, check your markup or post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrong assembly? [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) belong to `mscorlib`

```
xmlns:io="clr-namespace:System.IO;assembly=mscorlib"
```

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type io:FileInfo}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=FullName}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

- my project type is WPF Application

Comment: Note: Don't be confused when DirectoryInfo and FileInfo are not shown in the inputgesture of Visual Studio, the types are there and you can use the types as intended.